# How to Move a WordPress Site from a Server to localserver

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to word press.I have a .tar.gz  bundle and db.sql of a site,no i want to move it on my local server for some development.The problem that i am facing is when i run it on my xammp server it runs but redirect to its site url and when i run it on wamp it gives me 500 internal server error

Comment: Please search before asking : http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Enable `mod_rewrite` in localhost
- create database and import the dumped file
- change in database, in table `wp_options` the `siteurl` to `localhost`
- change your `wp-config.php` to use database user, pass, dbname and host.

Comment: hello Mihai
thanks for reply .I am going to try this,can u please tell me that
is there any problem that it is not running on to the wamp but still running on xammp with url redirection

Comment: That depends on your installation, but redirection is from table `wp_options`

Comment: hello Mahi, i have done all the steps that you have mentioned but still it is redirecting to the same url

Comment: Maybe the browser cached the redirect. Try to open from another browser. Also check in google chrome console where it tries to redirect and why.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Database in local server (PHPMYADMIN) and chnage the old URL to NEW url from WP_OPTIONS table and also change in WP.CONFIG.php. Chnage Database name, Username and Password.

Answer (score 1):

steps for you:
1. open .sql file in editor, find and replace old website url with your new url(on local it link localhost/mywordpress) and save it.

1. open localhost/phpmyadmin, create new database. import you modified .sql file.
2. extract all files from the zipped folder, copy and paste them in your folder in www.open config.php file, change dbname,pass,username,hostname. save it.

you're done. you path is now, localhost/mywordpress.

happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Moving Wordpress to different URL is tricky, because website URL is in the database at many places. You can "find and replace" but I recommend this interesting workaround: you set up your devel site at the SAME URL as your production site.

You can then manually switch these two with editing `hosts file` or use automatic `hosts` switching software, for example http://hostprofiles.codeplex.com/